# How does one list users belonging to a group in OSX?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, usergroups

I have been googling this problem to no avail.
I want to list just the users belonging to a particular group without extraneous data in osx terminal, I thought the dscl utility would be capable of doing this but so far I have been unable to craft out the right command if indeed it is capable of such an act.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To query a local group:

```
$ dscl . -read /groups/<groupname> | grep GroupMembership
```

Comment: Had to replace <groupname> with an actual group name..duh!  Then it worked `code` dscl . -read /groups/staff | grep GroupMembership

Comment: You don't really need the "grep GroupMembership" part, you can list the command as:

$ dscl . -read /groups/<groupname> GroupMembership

Answer (score 4):

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name staff
```

or

```
dscacheutil -q group -a name admin
```

etc...   get it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this shell function, which calls `dsmemberutil checkmembership` for every user. For example: `members everyone`. (Source: https://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-mac-os-x )

```
members () { dscl . -list /Users | while read user; do printf "$user "; dsmemberutil checkmembership -U "$user" -G "$*"; done | grep "is a member" | cut -d " " -f 1; }; 

members <group>
```

Other methods using `dscl . -read` and `dscacheutil` are incomplete. For example:

```
dscl . -read /groups/everyone | grep GroupMembership
dscacheutil -q group -a name everyone
```

do not list any users, whereas the shell function does.